# How do I concatenate within a JSON object?

Tags: ruby, json

I created a variable in Ruby:

```
@var = 5
```

Now I would like to use that variable in this object:

```
@json = '{"id":0,"observation": [{"key": "BLAH_BLAH","value": ["SOMETHING"]}'
```

Something like:

```
@json = '{"id":#{@var},"observation": [{"key": "BLAH_BLAH","value": ["SOMETHING"]}'
```

When I remove the double quotes from within the object and replace them with single quotes then wrap the JSON object in double quotes I receive a parsing error. When I try to escape the quotes with `\` I also get a parsing error:

```
@json = "{\"id\":\"#{@var}\",\"observation\": [{\"key\": \"BLAH_BLAH\",\"value\": [\"SOMETHING\"]}"
```

Might there be another way to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you're using single quotes to build the JSON string, and inside single quotes in Ruby, interpolation does not happen.

A simpler example:

```
a = 1
puts '#{a}'
puts "#{a}"
```

---

I would really recommend using a library to build your JSON, such as the built-in `JSON` module within Ruby.

```
require 'json'
JSON.generate(:id => @var, :observation => { :key => "blah blah", :value => ["something"] })
```

Comment: Absolutely. Do not think you can just use `#{var}` and get the right thing out. If anything you should be using `#{var.to_json}` if you have a JSON library that does that, like within Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON class to manipulate JSON strings:

```
require 'json'

json = '{"id":0,"observation":[{"key":"BLAH_BLAH","value":["SOMETHING"]}]}'

foo = JSON[json]  # => {"id"=>0, "observation"=>[{"key"=>"BLAH_BLAH", "value"=>["SOMETHING"]}]}
foo['id'] = 5
puts JSON[foo]

# >> {"id":5,"observation":[{"key":"BLAH_BLAH","value":["SOMETHING"]}]}
```

There are lots of special things that can happen when dealing with unknown structures and objects, that interpolation into a string won't cover. You should take advantage of the pre-built wheels and not try to invent or circumvent using them.

Answer (score -1):

*sigh* after being frustrated for countless minutes I found the solution to be:

```
"{\"id\":#{@u_id},\"observation\": [{\"key\": \"ACCOUNT_CLOSED\",\"value\": [\"N\"]}
```

I hate it when its something so simple.

Comment: Don't manipulate JSON like that. Use the JSON class to generate it for you.

Comment: You could avoid a lot of this escaping mess by using something like `%Q<...>` so that your quotation marks don't need to be escaped each time. `%Q` can use `{}` or `[]` but since JSON uses both of these, angle brackets are probably the safest.

Comment: Don't hand code JSON. Use `JSON.generate()`. You will save yourself a lot of headaches.